# Adding a "0." or a "0.0" to the begining of some numbers inside a character string

Tags: r

I have some data which looks like:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 2
     grp cents                                                             
   <int> <chr>                                                             
 1  4625 "48 cents to 49 cents\n34 cents to 38 cents"                      
 2  5832 "71 cents to 79 cents"                                            
 3  6131 "5 cents to 10 cents"                                             
 4  5719 "71 cents to 76 cents\n71 cents to 78 cents"                      
 5  4998 "37 cents to 50 cents\n40 cents to 56 cents"                      
 6  6579 "92 cents to 94 cents"
```

I clean the `cents` column using:

```
d %>% 
  mutate(
    cents = str_replace_all(cents, "cents to", "-"),
    cents = str_replace_all(cents, "cents", "")
  )
```

Which now looks like:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 2
     grp cents                         
   <int> <chr>                         
 1  4625 "48 - 49 \n34 - 38 "          
 2  5832 "71 - 79 "                    
 3  6131 "5 - 10 "                     
 4  5719 "71 - 76 \n71 - 78 "          
 5  4998 "37 - 50 \n40 - 56 "          
 6  6579 "92 - 94 "                    
 7  4074 "47 - 51 \n42 - 50
```

I want to add a `0.` or a `0.0` to each of the numbers such that the final data Will look like:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 2
     grp cents                         
   <int> <chr>                         
 1  4625 "0.48 - 0.49 \n0.34 - 0.38 "          
 2  5832 "0.71 - 0.79 "                    
 3  6131 "0.05 - 0.10 "                   # NOTE: Here                
 4  5719 "0.71 - 0.76 \n0.71 - 0.78 "          
 5  4998 "0.37 - 0.50 \n0.40 - 0.56 "          
 6  6579 "0.92 - 0.94 "                    
 7  4074 "0.47 - 0.51 \n0.42 - 0.50
```

I put a note in the data since just adding a `0.` to the following line:

```
 3  6131 "5 - 10 "
```

Would give an incorrect result. So for this line I would like `0.05 - 0.10`. So I want to add some sort of condition that if the number has 1 digit add a `0.0X` if the number has two digits add `0.X`.

Data:

```
d <- structure(list(grp = c(4625L, 5832L, 6131L, 5719L, 4998L, 6579L, 
4074L, 3663L, 766L, 911L, 3051L, 348L, 6062L, 7533L, 2714L, 2309L, 
6072L, 569L, 1555L, 2753L), cents = c("48 cents to 49 cents\n34 cents to 38 cents", 
"71 cents to 79 cents", "5 cents to 10 cents", "71 cents to 76 cents\n71 cents to 78 cents", 
"37 cents to 50 cents\n40 cents to 56 cents", "92 cents to 94 cents", 
"47 cents to 51 cents\n42 cents to 50 cents", "13 cents to 15 cents", 
"5 cents to 6 cents\n24 cents to 25 cents", "12 cents to 27 cents\n43 cents to 58 cents", 
"46 cents to 62 cents", "82 cents to 88 cents", "3 cents to 10 cents", 
"45 cents to 51 cents", "4 cents to 8 cents", "3 cents to 10 cents\n23 cents to 30 cents", 
"38 cents to 42 cents", "15 cents to 25 cents", "14 cents to 17 cents", 
"33 cents to 35 cents\n33 cents to 35 cents\n33 cents to 35 cents"
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use capturing groups, like this:

```r
d %>% 
  mutate(
    cents = str_replace_all(cents, "cents to", "-"),
    cents = str_replace_all(cents, "cents", ""),
    cents = str_replace_all(cents, "(\\b\\d{1}\\b)", "0\\1"),
    cents = str_replace_all(cents, "(\\b\\d{2}\\b)", "0.\\1")
  )
#> # A tibble: 20 x 2
#>      grp cents                                     
#>    <int> <chr>                                     
#>  1  4625 "0.48 - 0.49 \n0.34 - 0.38 "              
#>  2  5832 "0.71 - 0.79 "                            
#>  3  6131 "0.05 - 0.10 "                            
#>  4  5719 "0.71 - 0.76 \n0.71 - 0.78 "              
#>  5  4998 "0.37 - 0.50 \n0.40 - 0.56 "              
#>  6  6579 "0.92 - 0.94 "                            
#>  7  4074 "0.47 - 0.51 \n0.42 - 0.50 "              
#>  8  3663 "0.13 - 0.15 "                            
#>  9   766 "0.05 - 0.06 \n0.24 - 0.25 "              
#> 10   911 "0.12 - 0.27 \n0.43 - 0.58 "              
#> 11  3051 "0.46 - 0.62 "                            
#> 12   348 "0.82 - 0.88 "                            
#> 13  6062 "0.03 - 0.10 "                            
#> 14  7533 "0.45 - 0.51 "                            
#> 15  2714 "0.04 - 0.08 "                            
#> 16  2309 "0.03 - 0.10 \n0.23 - 0.30 "              
#> 17  6072 "0.38 - 0.42 "                            
#> 18   569 "0.15 - 0.25 "                            
#> 19  1555 "0.14 - 0.17 "                            
#> 20  2753 "0.33 - 0.35 \n0.33 - 0.35 \n0.33 - 0.35 "
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also use this in a single `str_replace_all`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
   mutate(cents = str_replace_all(cents,
     "(\\d+)\\s+cents\\s+to\\s+(\\d+)\\s+cents", "0.\\1 -  0.\\2"))
# A tibble: 20 x 2
#     grp cents                                     
#   <int> <chr>                                     
# 1  4625 "0.48 -  0.49\n0.34 -  0.38"              
# 2  5832 "0.71 -  0.79"                            
# 3  6131 "0.5 -  0.10"                             
# 4  5719 "0.71 -  0.76\n0.71 -  0.78"              
# 5  4998 "0.37 -  0.50\n0.40 -  0.56"              
# 6  6579 "0.92 -  0.94"                            
# 7  4074 "0.47 -  0.51\n0.42 -  0.50"              
# 8  3663 "0.13 -  0.15"                            
# 9   766 "0.5 -  0.6\n0.24 -  0.25"                
#10   911 "0.12 -  0.27\n0.43 -  0.58"              
#11  3051 "0.46 -  0.62"                            
#12   348 "0.82 -  0.88"                            
#13  6062 "0.3 -  0.10"                             
#14  7533 "0.45 -  0.51"                            
#15  2714 "0.4 -  0.8"                              
#16  2309 "0.3 -  0.10\n0.23 -  0.30"               
#17  6072 "0.38 -  0.42"                            
#18   569 "0.15 -  0.25"                            
#19  1555 "0.14 -  0.17"                            
#20  2753 "0.33 -  0.35\n0.33 -  0.35\n0.33 -  0.35"
```